# Image data from TCP/IP Python

Tags: python, tcp, tcpclient, ip-camera

Am working on a project of transmission from a robot camera to my 'PC' with tcp/ip protocol (Ethernet cable), so the robot has a web interface in which I can see the camera (the web interface is like the router one, I have access to it by typing the IP address in my browser).So I want to get this image/video data into my python project! My questions are:

1. How can I know which data are the image?
2. Which library allow me to get it? (socket ?)
3. I use now `urllib` to get the image/video and show it in cv2's window, but this is not what I wanted to do, I want to get directly the data from the IP address.

Thank you.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
from http.client import IncompleteRead

url = 'http://192.168.1.100/TD/VDEV_IMS.PNG'
while True:
    reponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(reponse.read()), dtype=np.uint8)

    reponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imgNp = np.array(bytearray(reponse.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(imgNp, -1)
    try:
        cv2.imshow("test", img)
    except IncompleteRead:
        return
    if ord('q') == cv2.waitKey(10):
        exit(0)
```